# checkbox not working repetatively while checking and unchecking using checkall cehckbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**Here is my script code**:

```
$(document).on("click", "#checkAll", function () {
    var isSelected = false;
    var i = 0;
    $('#domain_popup_grid table tr').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("input[id*='Checked']").length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < $(this).find("input[id*='Checked']").length; i++) {
                if ($(this).find("input[id*='Checked']")[i].checked == false) {
                    isSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    if (isSelected == true) {
        $("#domain_popup_grid tbody input:checkbox").attr("checked", "");
    } else {
        $("#domain_popup_grid tbody input:checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    }
})
```

**This is my view**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageGroups", "Admin"))
{
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Add(m => m.TagId)
.Titled("<input id='checkAll', type='checkbox' />")
.Sanitized(false)
.Encoded(false)
.RenderValueAs(d => Html.CheckBox(("Checked"), false));
columns.Add(alarm => alarm.GroupName).Titled("Groups").Sortable(true);
}).Sortable(true)    
<button id="SaveGroup" class="btn btn-primary pull-right img-responsive" >
Save
</button>
}
```

By using above code I can able to checkall checkbox once only not able to repeat again and again.
can any help to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checked status

```
$("#domain_popup_grid tbody input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vy9ZJ/1/), [Soution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vy9ZJ/)

Read: [Prop Vs Attr](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)